# How to add uipicker view in ui tableview in did selected row method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to add `UIPickerView` in `UITableView` in `didSelectRow` method ,

Based on picker selection user select different options  in each cell

Comment: you want picker in each row or only when user selects a row ?

Comment: Did you tried something ??

Comment: i want to show in each row

Comment: can you show some images how you want to add...or some code

Answer (score 0):

**First, when you want to ask a question, you should add some code pieces that you tried. In this way, people can help you using your work.**

ANYWAY, I suggest you two ways:

1. Create a custom `UITableViewCell` class and in `setSelected:` method create a `UIPickerView` and add it to window. Set its `delegate` and `dataSource`. Use `delegate` methods to get data and use `dataSource` methods to set data to `UIPickerView`.
2. In `UITableView`'s `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method and implement `UIPickerView` `delegate` and `dataSource` methods same as in first option. Update cells' data using these methods.